# How to plot marker at beggining and end points using matplotlib

Tags: python

How can I automate a code so that I can place a marker for the starting and end points of this plot using matplotlib.pyplot?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 9, 9)
y = x**2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be just to overplot 2 points (being the begining and end points) ontop of your current plot. Using plt.figure(), we can have two plots ontop of each other.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 9, 9)
y = x**2

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.scatter([x[0],x[-1]], [y[0],y[-1]])
```

Futhermore, this can be automatated by declare your own function which plots two plots on top automatically:

```
def plot(x,y):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.scatter([x[0],x[-1]], [y[0],y[-1]])
```

[image: Two plots over plotted ontop of each other]